# I suddenly get a fatal error. I don't understand it

Tags: php

I have been working at a code that used to work. However, suddenly, this message pops up.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Email is incorrect!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype\classes\User.php:23
>
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype\index.php(14): User->setEmail(true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype\classes\User.php on line 23

But I just don't understand what this means. I tried using try and catch, but it keeps popping up.

This is the code where the error occurs

```
public function setEmail($p_email)
{
    if (empty($p_email)) {
        throw new Exception('Email kan niet leeg zijn!');
    }
    $this->email = $p_email;
    if (!filter_var($p_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new Exception('Email is incorrect!'); //here is the error (line 23)
    }
}
```

this is the code where it is summoned

```
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail($_SESSION['login']); //line 14
$currentUser = $user->getProfile();
$userEmail = $user->getEmail();
$userName = $user->getUserName();
$userID = $currentUser['userID'];
```

Comment: what does `echo $_SESSION['login'];` prints ?

Comment: You're trying to set the email to true (`User->setEmail(true)`) which is not an email address. Are you sure you want to pass in the Session login value?

Comment: why are you passing "login status" as email?

Comment: It should probably be something like `$_SESSION['email']`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are passing a `boolean` instead of a valid `string` email...

> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype\index.php(14): User->setEmail(**true**) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype\classes\User.php on line 23

So, this line is incorrect:

```
$user->setEmail($_SESSION['login']); //line 14
```

Comment: I tried changing 'login' to 'user'. But then I can't login in anymore.